# How do you represent a random choice of random variables mathematically? What is its mean, variance, etc.?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Suppose that I have six random variables $X_1, X_2,\ldots,X_6$ (say, e.g., six coins with different biases). We should be able to get a new random variable $Y$ by rolling a die to get a number $n\in \{1,\ldots,6\}$ and returning the value of $X_n$.

How would I represent $Y$ mathematically? How can I calculate its mean and variance?

Comment: [Mixture distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixture_distribution)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific example, suppose $X_i\sim\mathrm{Ber}(p_i)$ for $i=1,\ldots,6$ and $Z$ is uniformly distributed on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, independent of the $X_i$. Then
$$Y = \sum_{i=1}^6 X_i 1_{\{Z=i\}}. $$

By independence,
$$\mathbb E[Y] = \sum_{i=1}^6\mathbb E[X_i1_{\{Z=i\}}]=\sum_{i=1}^6 \mathbb E[X_i]\mathbb P(Z=i)=\frac16\sum_{i=1}^6 p_i. $$
The variance can be computed similarly.